# JBoss JMS Remote Queue?

Tags: jboss, jms, message-queue

I want to send messages to remote queue ? what steps should i do 
i cant find any documentation about that ? 
anyone can help ?? ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add another "JMSProvider" in your ${JBOSS_CONF}/deploy/messaging/jms-ds.xml. I use the provider name "RemoteJMSProvider" in this example:

```
<!-- Remote JMS Server-->
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.jndi.JMSProviderLoader"
  name="jboss.mq:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=RemoteJMSProvider,server=your_remote_host">
    <attribute name="ProviderName">RemoteJMSProvider</attribute>
    <attribute name="ProviderAdapterClass">org.jboss.jms.jndi.JNDIProviderAdapter</attribute>
    <!-- The connection factory -->
    <attribute name="FactoryRef">XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <!-- The queue connection factory -->
    <attribute name="QueueFactoryRef">XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <!-- The topic factory -->
    <attribute name="TopicFactoryRef">XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <!-- Connect to JNDI on the host "the-remote-host-name" port 1099-->
    <attribute name="Properties">
       java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
       java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jnp.interfaces
       java.naming.provider.url=your_remote_host:1099
    </attribute>
```

Next, add a "Remote Connection Factory":

```
<tx-connection-factory>
  <jndi-name>RemoteJMSConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
  <xa-transaction/>
  <rar-name>jms-ra.rar</rar-name>
  <connection-definition>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory</connection-definition>
  <config-property name="SessionDefaultType" type="java.lang.String">javax.jms.Queue</config-property>
  <config-property name="JmsProviderAdapterJNDI" type="java.lang.String">java:/RemoteJMSProvider</config-property>
  <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
  <security-domain-and-application>JmsXARealm</security-domain-and-application>
  <depends>jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
```

Now, anytime you create a connection factory reference to "RemoteJMSFactory", any queue you reference will be looked-up on the remote server:

```
ConnectionFactory factory =(ConnectionFactory)JNDIContext.lookup("java:/RemoteJMSConnectionFactory");
queue = (Destination) JNDIContext.lookup("queue/myqueue");
connection = factory.createConnection();
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(queue);
sender.send(jmsMessage);
```

See also:
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoIConfigureAnMDBToTalkToARemoteQueue

Comment: Will this work for Remote Topic. I am using EJB3 MDB on JBOSS to listen to a remote topic on IBM MQ.

Answer (score 0):

Look in docs/examples of your jboss installation.  The only change needed to connect to a remote queue is to set up your initial context to refer to the remote appserver's JNDI port.